# javax.net.ssl|ERROR|83|reactor-http-nio-12|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify (

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

*What I am trying to achieve:*

Send a high volume of http requests to a third party server

*Issue:*

Intermittently, I am facing this issue I am having a hard time understanding.

Again, this is intermittent only.

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|83|reactor-http-nio-12|SSLEngineImpl.java:825|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|83|reactor-http-nio-12|SSLEngineImpl.java:786|Closing inbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|83|reactor-http-nio-12|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:796)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1878)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1078)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}
```

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|53|reactor-http-nio-10|SSLEngineImpl.java:786|Closing inbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|33|reactor-http-nio-8|SSLEngineImpl.java:825|Closing outbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ALL|33|reactor-http-nio-8|SSLEngineImpl.java:786|Closing inbound of SSLEngine
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|53|reactor-http-nio-10|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:796)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1878)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1078)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at reactor.netty.channel.MicrometerChannelMetricsHandler$TlsMetricsHandler.channelInactive(MicrometerChannelMetricsHandler.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasksFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:426)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:375)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.confirmShutdown(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:763)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:596)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}
```

```
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|6B|HttpClient@684b31de-182|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (INTERNAL_ERROR): closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:358)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:305)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.closeInbound(SslConnection.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)}
```

*Note:*

Other clients, running on same machine or different machines, when they fire requests at the same timestamp, no issue

*Question:*

May I ask what does it mean?

Is it the third party server issue? Or me the client?

What can I do in order to avoid this? What can I do to further debug this issue?

Comment: This is a bug in Netty and Jetty respectively. Report it to them, and have a look through their bug lists.

Comment: Something similar: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/12087